# create own x-axis graduation

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis, rescale

I'm looking to adapt the x-scale of my graph with the ggplot2 library

Here is a example of what I mean:

```
example <- data.frame(a = 1:2000, b = rnorm(n = 2000))
ggplot(example,aes(a,b)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 5)
```

Giving me this plot

[image]

What I want to do is to change the breaks of the x-axis so that its scale is not linear anymore.

As a example I'm looking to change the values of the breaks 500,1000,1500 to 2,20,200 respectively. The graph needs to adapt to this change of scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can log transform an axis with base 10 using `scale_x_log10`, then use `scales::trans_breaks` to set your desired breaks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

set.seed(123)
example <- data.frame(a = 1:2000, b = rnorm(n = 2000))

ggplot(example, aes(a, b)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 2*10^x))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: simple enough thank you !